# CMake add_definitions does not seem to work

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to define a preprocessor variable via CMake, but unfortunately it does not seem to work.

The following is my c++ code:

```
     #ifdef hehe_test
     #define it_exists "it_exists"
     #endif

     #ifndef hehe_test
     #define it_exists "it_doesnt_exist"
     #endif

     int main(int argc, char** argv)
     {
        printf("%s\n",it_exists);

        return 0;
    }
```

And this is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
    project(LibraryTester)

    add_definitions(hehe_test)

    file(GLOB src "*.h" "*.cpp")

    include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

    add_executable( ${PROJECT_NAME} ${src})
```

When i run my program it outputs: it_doesnt_exist 
indicating "hehe_test" has not been defined.

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Should be `add_definitions(-Dhehe_test)`. See the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following form won't do what you expect in any case:

```
add_definitions(hehe_test)
```

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html) the form is:

```
add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)
```

In your case it means:

```
add_definitions(-Dhehe_test)
```

You can also give them a value if required:

```
// statically defined
add_definitions(-Dfoo=bar)
// use a cmake or user-defined variable 
add_definitions(-Dbar=${FOO})
// use "" if you intend to pass strings with spaces
add_definitions(-Dxxx="${YYY}")
```

Note that you can put all of them together in the same `add_definitions` call.

Comment: "use "" if you intend to pass strings with spaces" ? Could you please explain that more in detail?

Comment: @John probably CMake will stop parsing at space, similarly how sometimes in terminal you must quote stuff.

Answer (score 8):

In order to get the C/C++ effect of :

```
#define _MYSYMBOL
```

From the command line you can :

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=" -D_MYSYMBOL " -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=" -D_MYSYMBOL "
```

From within CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -D_MYSYMBOL")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -D_MYSYMBOL")
```

These add flags to the c/c++ compiler command directly. 
-D is define symbol

You can also use cmake's `add_definitions` command

```
add_definitions ( -D_MYSYMBOL1 -D_MYSYMBOL2 )
```

`add_definitions` makes some slight assumptions as described [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_definitions.html)

Comment: While technically true, there is on reason to pass definitions as other flags when CMake has a dedicated mechanism (such as `add_definitions()` which the OP uses).